# modal not working on heroku; but works fine locally

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, modal-dialog

Simple bootstrap modal triggered by a button that once it's pushed to heroku, the modal no longer shows up when the button is clicked. I can't seem to figure out why, I've tried all solutions I could find online but none have worked. I am using the exact modal/button combo off of the bootstrap site, removed my customization until I was sure I could get it functioning onto Heroku. HTML below. Here's the link to my heroku app - http://themommyboxco.herokuapp.com/

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal 
</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-    labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        This modal is not showing up on heroku!
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the live?

Comment: yup - http://themommyboxco.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your application.js, line 13371

```
$(function() 
  $("#menu").click(function() {
```

Should be:

```
$(function() {
  $("#menu").click(function() {
```

Make sure the closing tag is there later too.

Comment: How do you see that? My application.js file pulls other javascript; the website is created as a rails app and I haven't imported any specific javascript. I actually tried importing the modal js specifically but it didn't change the situation. Where can I see what you're pointing out so I can edit it? PS. thank you for helping me.

Comment: That makes it a little trickier to track down. It's in the final application.js though, here:

http://themommyboxco.herokuapp.com/assets/application-692bbbe35437acf7826dfe2589d452e1.js

If you open Chrome developer tools (Control-Shift-J) you'll see the error in the console.